# PGF barplot with pgfplotstable and secondary y-axis doesn't look good

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to create a bar chart with two y-axes. My data is included in the file and used with `pgfplotstable`. I've looked at [PGF barplot with two y axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273779/pgf-barplot-with-two-y-axis)

I have a few issues that I can't seem to resolve:

1. Secondary y-axis label is on top of primary y-axis label
2. The x-ticks are duplicated.
3. The `Time` data isn't being shown. Is it not being read correctly from the table?
4. Why do I need to have `symbolic x coords={llvm, gcc}` in both axes?

I'm fairly new to pgfplots/tikz so please forgive my ignorance. **Are there any other things I could do to clean this up?**

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Compiler    Time      Memory
llvm        100       2.61
gcc         110       2.90
}{\CompilerComparison}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        axis y line*=left,
        symbolic x coords={llvm, gcc},
        ylabel={Compile Time (s)},
        xtick=data,
      ]
      \addplot[color=red,fill=red] 
        table[x=Compiler,y=Time]{\CompilerComparison}; \label{Time}
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={Memory Consumption (GB)},
        ymin=0,
        symbolic x coords={llvm, gcc},
        xtick=data,
        legend style={
          at={(0.5,0.9)},
          anchor=north
        }
      ]
      \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Time}\addlegendentry{Time}

      \addplot[color=blue,fill=blue]
        table[x=Compiler,y=Memory]{\CompilerComparison}; \label{Memory}
      \legend{Time, Memory}
    \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` to the preamble.
2. I think you want `xticklabels={}` for the second axis to remove the ticklabels for that.
3. The time data are shown, but are behind the memory bars. No shifting is done when there is just one barplot in an axis, see [Plotting grouped bar chart with 2 sets of y-axes in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478928) for a fix.
4. Why would you not need it? There is no connection between the axes, the second one doesn't know what the first did. (That said, because you only use the first one for the labels, you could use numbers, but I think it makes more sense to use the same setup for both axes.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Compiler    Time      Memory
llvm        100       2.61
gcc         110       2.90
}{\CompilerComparison}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
   declare function={
    barW=8pt; % width of bars
    barShift=barW/2; % bar shift
  }
]
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=barW,
        bar shift=-barShift,
        axis y line*=left,
        symbolic x coords={llvm, gcc},
        ylabel={Compile Time (s)},
        xtick=data,
      ]
      \addplot[color=red,fill=red] 
        table[x=Compiler,y=Time]{\CompilerComparison}; \label{Time}
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=barW,
        bar shift=barShift,
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={Memory Consumption (GB)},
        ymin=0,
        symbolic x coords={llvm, gcc},
        xticklabels={},
        xtick=data,
        legend style={
          at={(0.5,0.9)},
          anchor=north
        }
      ]
      \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Time}\addlegendentry{Time}

      \addplot[color=blue,fill=blue]
        table[x=Compiler,y=Memory]{\CompilerComparison}; \label{Memory}
      \legend{Time, Memory}
    \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is **a lot** I have to learn about pgfplots. I'm afraid the only way is to ask lots of questions. Thanks for being patient and helpful.